# power point font changing on closing and reopening

Tags: powerpoint

I have created a ppt by copying the slides from another power point. 
When both the power points are opened together then the fonts look okay, but if open the one i created alone then fonts get messed up.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a forum where you can get help with writing programs; it's not for problems using programs that someone else has written. Your question is better suited for the sister forum, SuperUser.  I'd ask there instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am new and learning things around here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The font in the first ppt was not available in the power-point. 
so when both were open simultaneously the font was getting loaded in the system, however when it was opened alone the font was not getting recognized and getting changed.

Changed the fonts manually in my ppt to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like the second PPT had the font embedded.  Interesting behavioral quirk, this.  Thanks for coming back with the report.